# Probabilistic timed automata transition

Tags: pr.probability, automata-theory

I am kind of new to timed automata and I have a question related to their correctness and synchronisation.

Assume that I have three states, A, B and C. I have also two clocks, $x$ and $y$ that are global clocks. Once $x$ (resp. $y$) becomes greater than a given value $VALUE\_1$ (resp. $VALUE\_2$) then a transition to state $B$ (resp. $C$) becomes possible, with a probability of $P(A,C)$ (resp. $P(A,B)$). My question is: is it correct? What can we do if $VALUE_1 = VALUE_2$ and $P(A,B) = P(A,C)$? If it is not correct, how may I fix this? Thanks a lot.[image: Quick example]

Comment: It sounds correct, and it should not matter what the actual values are. Often there is a mechanism that does the tests in some sequence and then enables the transition when the first enabling trigger is encountered. (So if both conditions for x and y are present, if the mechanism looks at y first, then the y condition triggers the respective transition.) You should check with the instructor or related texts for the details for your situation.  Gerhard "Your Timing Conditions May Vary" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: Also, this is not the best forum for your question.  If you are studying the theory, the computer science forums are better. If you are implementing this in software or hardware, the programming / engineering forums are better.  Gerhard "There's A Place For Everything" Paseman, 2018.06.25.